# Submitting $_POST variables on pageload without refresh

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have two pages, Page_A.php and Page_B.php. Page_A.php is where a user fills out a form and clicks submit which directs them to Page_B.php. Page_B.php acts as sort of a confirmation page with a hidden form capturing the values and displaying relevant information in the labels. I've checked the hidden inputs and they are infact capturing the values.

I am trying to submit the form on pageload without refreshing the page. I've tried doing this with Ajax but can't seem to get the form to submit. Looking for any advice here

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        ajax();
    });
    function ajax(){
        var url = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/pricing-form/form-handler.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data:$( "#hidden-form" ).serialize(),
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (response) {
                $("#prores").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML

Comment: What does the ajax response says, Check in browser console

Comment: This would be for Page_B.php? You forgot to put the hash in the selector here: `data : $('hidden-form').serialize()`.

Comment: You need to remove `$('#hidden-form').submit(ajax);`.  You don't want to literally submit the form. You just want to perform the ajax call on page load.  The reason you are performing ajax call is so you can avoid having to actually submit the form, because submitting the form will cause page load.

Comment: @BryanElliott but will placing function ajax() inside the $(document).ready(function() { } submit the form on pageload?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why are you trying to submit the form on page load? Won't it be empty?

Comment: @Nick, Oh, actually, I see another problem.  The way you're doing will work..  just add the event parameter in your ajax function, like this: `function ajax(e) {`. Notice the `e`.

Comment: The `e` argument will allow `e.preventDefault();` to work as expected.

Comment: @TheCodesee Because the form was already submitted on the previous page but being that there's a redirect the &_POST variables wont transfer. So to eliminate that I'm trying to actually submit the form on the last page to allow the data to transfer from page to page.

Comment: @BryanElliott I'm slightly lost, so how should the code look?

Comment: just simply add `e` in the parenthesis of the ajax function. like this: `function ajax(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({ ....})`.  Doing that will allow the `e.preventDefault();` command to work, preventing the browsers default behavior of page reload when submitting the form.  But without passing in `e` into the ajax function, e.preventDefault(); does nothing.. (or probably causes error).

Comment: @BryanElliott does this need to be inside the `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`

Comment: No, however I would maybe change `$(document).ready(function(){` to `$(window).load(function(){` ... But probably not necessary..  Depends on where the script in question is located in your html document (In <head> or just before </body>?)

Comment: @nick, Yes, Deepak's answer would be a great way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do something like below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    ajax();
});
function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'target url',
        type : 'POST',
        data : $('#hidden-form').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
    return false;
};

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I am receiving a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined when using this method. I've updated my original code in the post to what I currently have.

Comment: I suspect this line the line  var url = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/pricing-form/form-handler.php"; can you check if url is correctly return by this line.

Comment: Yes that's the correct path of the form-handler.php file

Comment: I tried <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?> at my server and its not running at my end...can you manually type complete url and check for testing.